# 'Debian Software' tab in Software & Updates

Tags: release-freya, software-sources

This is something very weird. I am running Elementary OS 0.32 Freya 64-bit (build on Ubuntu 14.04) for a few months now and as such, it comes with Ubuntu's Software Center and Software & Updates applications.

I don't remember when this first appeared (I practically don't use Software Center nor go to Software & Updates), but as I tried updating after adding the wine builds ppa (`ppa:wine/wine-builds`), I got this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/sid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

When looking at the .list file added in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, I noticed that this was what was in there:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu sid main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu sid main
```

which I know is not what is supposed to be in there. I corrected the file for the wine ppa (replaced sid by trusty), but each time I add a new ppa, it will have the same format as the one above and I'll have to change it manually every single time.

My Software & Updates looks like this:
[Software & Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJwfT.png) which is also not normal.

***Why could it be that I have 'Debian Software' instead of 'Ubuntu Software', like it was when I originally installed eOS, in my 'Software & Updates' ?***

'Software & Updates' basically started doing like if I was running a Debian system, so the servers listed changed to debian servers, etc... However, only that tab provides me with Debian related stuff, the other tabs are all good (updates and the others).